# Could not find the expected embedded asset at-rules.json. Check that expo-updates is installed correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, expo

I'm pretty new to react native, I recently ran into this issue and this happens when i try to run the app on ios from xcode and it crashes on load with this error. I've tried looking everywhere but i can't seem to find what at-rules.json is and also can't find where the check for it is coming from. Any suggestions would be helpful! If you need me to add any extra information please let me know and i'll add it right away!

Comment: encountered the same problem :(

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm still struggling with that.